# Xcode 10 localization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I am trying to add localization on my project. Right now I have my main project, and all the text in the Main Storyboard and the `.swift` classes is in language Norwegian. I have another project where everything is in English, but I want to only use one project with both languages, so I can have one app only on the app store. I have about 20 different classes, and some classes contain multiple arrays with over 400 strings each. How exactly do I add English language to my existing project?

Comment: Start with the [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH1-SW1). It's not 100% up-to-date but it's a good start.

Comment: @rmaddy I will have a look at it. Do I have to change the base language in Xcode from English(default) to Norwegian?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple guidelines, the default language of your app will be based on the user device default language settings.

To add localization to your xcode project, start by the adding the language you want from **Project navigator** -> **Info** -> **Localizations** tab and select the language you want to add. After selecting the language, a popup will appear to select the resource that you want to include in your localization:
[image]

You will notice that you will have a new .string file under your selected resource (for example, Main.storyboard) where you can do all the translation you want.

There are other topics like localizing strings from your code (for example, having  a .string and an extension to your String) or image localization.